# Revesal of Tax Preparation fee

Tags: civil

I feel like this is a fraud from one of the Indian tax consulting firm called universal financials. They are supposed to do a reversal of fee they charged on my card by April 2018. I did many follow ups over phone and recently sent reminders over email. There is no positive response as of now from them. Can someone guide me how can I complain this incident to bureaus about this firm? They have their office registered in NJ and this incident is happening in USA. Whenever I call them they say they need couple of days time or till month end. Now they stopped responding to emails and when reached over phone they say the senior is in meeting or the director is not available.

Thanks
VB

Comment: This seems to be a request for specific legal advice. We cannot answer such requests here.

Comment: Are you also in the USA?

Comment: @mkennedy, Yes I am in USA

Answer (score 1):

Complain to the Better Business Bureau (BBB).

File in small claims court.

File a complaint against the business at the [New Jersey Consumer Affairs](https://www.njconsumeraffairs.gov/Pages/File-a-Complaint.aspx)

Comment: I did it on www.ftccomplaintassistant.gov but not sure whether it is the right place.